# Syntax error using send method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a tiny but silly problem over here, i have a model action;

```
def self.price_change_up(network, currency, change )
    prices = Prices.where('network = ?', network) 
    prices.each do |price|
      price.send("#{currency}") = price.send("#{currency}") + change
      price.save
    end
  end
```

but the line

> price.send("#{currency}") = price.send("#{currency}") + change

return a syntax error. What could be the problem.

Comment: Please provide your stacktrace...

Comment: your controller action cannot start with self as you posted here

Comment: @GhostRider, i have made an edit, it was model action

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to do this instead:

```
price = price.send("#{currency}") + change
```

Your current example is invalid syntax because you are trying to *assign* something to a *value*, the return value of `price.send("#{currency}")` whatever may that be.

Answer (score 1):

> price.send("#{currency}") = price.send("#{currency}") + change

This is invalid, you can't use '=' to assign ,In case you are looking to use send with setter

```
 self.send("#{currency}=", prev_curr_value)
```

In the LHS, you are using price.send("#{currency}"), it calls a method dynamically and will return a value which is again being assigned to same value with some addition change which looks wierd. what are you trying to achieve here, explain with an updated qsn.

Comment: price.send("#{currency}=", price.send(currency) + change)